# Setting IFS in KSH

Tags: ksh

```
v_date=date1:date2:date3
```

I am trying to write a ksh to split dates into array.
i did

```
IFS=":"
set -A array $(echo $v_date)
```

This is not splittig the string into array
instead value of array is same as v_date.
Please help.

Comment: I did set -A array $(echo "${v_date}")

and it worked

Comment: or not use echo, just set -A array $v_date

Answer (score 0):

I did `set -A array $(echo "${v_date}")` and it worked